# How to move caret to the beginning of text inside a Textbox?

Tags: c#, .net

I tried using this code but It doesn't work

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            this.textBox1.Select(0, 0);

    }
```

I want whenever the user click on the textbox, the caret position will be at the beginning of text instead of being in the position when user clicked  ?

How to move caret to the beginning of text inside a Textbox ?

Comment: What if user right click on the textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `MouseClick` Event :

```
private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Select(0, 0);
}
```

Note that this will not work if you enter the TextBox through Tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectionStart and SelectionLenght property . for example ,
SelectionStart = 0;
Selectionlenght = 0;

You can use these code in Enter event .